# Debug exception

Tags: android, logcat

I'm trying to create an app and  at a point my program gets forced close.While I debug it I get this stack
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2496
Does anyone knows what it refers to?

Comment: Please include the logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see what causes that exception. Probably, following the trace, you'll find some line that says "caused by". There might be more than one, so be sure to follow all the way down, because it's the last one that counts, probably.

In this case, it seems something's going wrong while launching an activity (probably in `onCreate()`).

Also, note that in the LogCat you should be able to see the stacktrace even without debugging.